# Judges Chapter 9 and Aesop's Fable

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, shoftim--book-of, allegory-mashal, literature

In the book of Judges 9:8-15 we have the following fable:

> 8 The trees went forth on a time to anoint a king over them; and they
>   said unto the olive-tree: Reign thou over us.
>
> 9 But the olive-tree said unto them: Should I leave my fatness, seeing
>   that by me they honour God and man, and go to hold sway over the
>   trees?
>
> 10 And the trees said to the fig-tree: Come thou, and reign over us.
>
> 11 But the fig-tree said unto them: Should I leave my sweetness, and
>   my good fruitage, and go to hold sway over the trees?
>
> 12 And the trees said unto the vine: Come thou, and reign over us.
>
> 13 And the vine said unto them: Should I leave my wine, which cheereth
>   God and man, and go to hold sway over the trees?
>
> 14 Then said all the trees unto the bramble: Come thou, and reign over
>   us.
>
> 15 And the bramble said unto the trees: If in truth ye anoint me king
>   over you, then come and take refuge in my shadow; and if not, let fire
>   come out of the bramble, and devour the cedars of Lebanon.
>
> ([Mechon-Mamre translation](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0709.htm))

The same fable appears almost identically in [Aesop's Fables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesop%27s_Fables):

> **The Logs and the Olive**
>
> Once the logs were consulting among themselves to elect a king. They
>   asked the olive:
>
> 'Reign over us.'
>
> The olive tree replied:
>
> 'What? Give up my oily liquor which is so highly prized by god and man
>   to go reign over the logs?'
>
> And so the logs asked the fig:
>
> 'Come and reign over us.'
>
> But the fig replied similarly:
>
> 'What? Relinquish the sweetness of my delicious fruit to go and reign
>   over the logs?'
>
> So the logs urged the thornbush:
>
> 'Come and reign over us.'
>
> And the thorn replied:
>
> 'If you were really to anoint me king over you, you would have to take
>   shelter beneath me. Otherwise the flames from my brushwood [a usual
>   tinder] would escape and devour the cedars of Lebanon.
>
> (Olivia & Robert Temple translation)

Have any rabbinic commentators made note of this, and if so what have they said about it?

Comment: This is intriguing. +1

Comment: Rashi notes how the fable relates to certain people and events in Tanach. The same hints would not be possible due to differences in Aesop's alternate version. I am not aware if or why Chazal did/would comment on the two as a connection? However, it wouldn't matter. It could be that A) a common parable pre-dates both. or B) Yotham's came first. But, C) "Aesop" making it up, doesn't seem possible since Yotham predates Aesop.

Comment: @David Kenner My question is kind of avoiding the discussion of who wrote what first. I'm just asking if any of the rabbinic commentators were aware that the same basic parable existed in a secular source, and if they had anything to say about that.

Comment: @Alex That's why it was a comment, not an answer. I don't think there is an answer btw. It is not usual to compare such things in Talmudic writings or commentary of the Rishonim.

Comment: Not from a Jewish source, yet provides useful info nonetheless: https://celsus.blog/2017/11/19/guest-blog-by-tyler-huson-jothams-fable-or-aesops-fable-a-discussion-of-textual-relations/

Comment: @ezra nice article. Divrei HaYamim II 25: 18-19 "And Joash the king of Israel sent to Amaziah the king of Judah, saying, "The thistle that was in Lebanon sent to the cedar that was in Lebanon, saying: Give your daughter to my son for a wife; and the wild beast that was in Lebanon passed by and trampled the thistle. You said that behold, you have defeated Edom, and your heart has made you haughty to seek glory. Now, stay in your home. Why should you provoke evil and fall, you and Judah with you?"   There is an example of yet another fable in the Tanach. Romer's position weakens.

Comment: And the Talmud says that Rabbi Meir would teach Proverbs using all sorts of stories about foxes. Sound familiar? There was likely some cross-pollination of ideas ...

Comment: I don't think the rabbis comment every time something from Torah is quoted in a different work. You can see in the the wiki page you linked to under the section of his fables: Fables wrongly attributed to Aesop. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trees_and_the_Bramble In this page we see 'An echo of that tradition, in which the trees instance their chief useful characteristics, is found in the earliest evidence of a fable among Jews occurring in the Hebrew Bible.' & 'The story began to be included in European fable collections in the Middle Ages.[9]' So this isn't more exciting than anyone

Comment: quoting Solomon's wisdom offering to split the child or the like.

Comment: @DavidKenner The singular "god" and the name "Lebanon" give the impression that the Hebrew source came first

Comment: Aesop lived long after the Book of Judges was written. Why would it surprise you that he copied us? Lots of Greek tales come from Tanach and Talmud.

Comment: @DonielF Why would you say that? It seems pretty close https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D#חיבור_הספר_בראי_המחקר

Comment: @AlBerko Your link’s broken. Aesop lived c. 620-564 BCE according to Wikipedia. Based on the numbers in Tanach, plus the tradition that Sefer Yehoshua took 14 years, means that this incident was in 2669 AM, or 1090 BCE.

Comment: @ba, yes, another strong reason to assume Judges came first is its use of 4 examples while "Aesop" uses 3. This is because popular fables almost always use 3 examples (as do classic jokes) because of the way a 3 example statement is readily received by the brain. 4 examples would therefore show a need to be organic for a specific purpose. The later one reduces it to 3 for commercialization, to gain popularity.

Comment: @AlBerko at the end of the day, it wouldn't matter if we knew that a prophet wished to use style they enjoyed from a foreign source. It has no issue with the validity of Nach. Even Torah has an authorized version of Balaam's prophecy/poetry as part of its verses. Whatever G-d authorizes, that's His business, right? :)

Comment: In [this essay](https://lib.cet.ac.il/pages/item.asp?item=14143&kwd=7156) it says that undoubtedly the LXX's version of Mashal Yotam was copied into Aesop's.

Answer (score -3):

I have a philosophical answer to "what **would** the Rabbis say", based on the "Lurianian" tradition.

1. According to it, many valuable pieces of Jewish souls together with pieces of the Torah fell into/onto the Gentiles in the times of the primordial sin (called ניצוצות), and thru the exiles and constant interaction and conversions and adoptions, those pieces reunite with the Jewish nation.
2. THis is the reason the Rabbis were so "eager" to adopt words from foreign languages (דברה תורה כלשון בני אדם), scientific facts (חכמה בגויים תאמין), foreign names, and of course, foreign converts etc.
3. When the Sages saw that the wisdom of the Torah emerged thru foreign cultures, they not only didn't oppose it but saw a Mitzvah of bringing it back to the domain of the Torah.

Therefore we (I and my Rabbis) see no contradiction in seeing foreign texts copied in our scriptures.

---

*Please don't downvote just because you don't agree or not familiar with those concepts in Judaism. Thank you.*

Comment: This is a great discussion, it may have missed to capture the essence of what Alex is asking

Comment: @Shmuel Please, don't just hint, if you know what's missing, elaborate it.

Comment: I’m not downvoting because I don’t agree or because I’m not familiar with these concepts; I’m downvoting because this doesn’t answer the question of if they did and what did they say; he didn’t ask for speculation of “if they did say anything, what would it be?”